# How to be able to pull data from xml where the roots and elements are variables from select box

Tags: php, javascript, xml, variables, hyperlink

I am pretty new to web coding and trying as a hobby to develop a quotation software for a digital printing company that will be able to give an instant quote to a potential customer.

I am struggling on a certain aspect of this and i hope that someone can help.

One point where i am struggling on is i have two select elements and one text box.

- select box 1 = z = options of if a print job is B/W or colour
- select box 1 = x = the size of the page (eg. A3, A4 or A5)
- text box  = c = will have a qty value.

(with the text box i have managed to make it so that firstly it only accepts numbers and secondly that if a number is between certain values then it will output a certain value for example if a number is between 1 to 20 then it will output the value of column1, if 21 to 300 column2 and so on)

The output from C (eg. column1) = V

Now what i would like to achieve is

- z = root node
- x = the child of z
- v = the child of x

now the value that is within the field of V on the xml should be output to a hidden field so that on the form i can easily create calculations of all the needed values to create the final end total price.

I dont know if i should do this in javascript, jquery, or if there is another way.

You can look at all i have done on link below

http://www.dtp2print.co.za/Quotation/Stack/

I have the one xml and the actual page.

IF there is any advice that anyone could give would also be greatly appreciated.

The result that i am trying to get to is basically this.

How i see things is Z is the table where all the data is on.

X is the row

V is the column

now the mutual value between X and V is the result that needs to be pulled.

for example

```
<Colour>
<Colour_Row>
<size>A6</size>
<Column1>1.29</Column1>
<Column2>0.76</Column2>
<Column3>0.635</Column3>
<Column4>0.52</Column4>
</Colour_Row>
```

Z = colour.xml

X = the specific size that is needed (eg. A6)

v= the column (eg. Column1)

the result that is needed is = 1.29

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not obvious what you are trying to achieve from your answer. Could you specify more what should be the *result*? "z=root node" is not very helpful.

Comment: but what do you intend to do with this value? Display it to the user? Process it by a PHP script?

Comment: Hi Mifeet, thanks for your quick response.


i have edited the question so please would you kindly see the information there. Thanks

Comment: The result doesnt need to be shown to the user, it will basically just produce a value that later on be used to calculate the final quotation price.

Comment: It's a nice question but difficult to understand from your formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getPrice() {
        var Z = "Colour.xml";
        var X = $("#size").val();
        var V = $("#column").val();

        function showPrice(xml) {
            var colourRow = $(xml).find("size:contains(" + X + ")").parent();
            var price = colourRow.find(V).text(); 
            alert(price);
        }
        $.get(Z, null, showPrice, "xml"); // AJAX request for the XML document
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Column: <select id="column">
    <option>Column1</option>
    <option>Column2</option>
    <option>Column3</option>
    <option>Column4</option>
</select>
<br />
Size: <select id="size">
    <option value="A3">A3</option>
    <option value="A4" selected="selected">A4</option>
    <option value="A5">A5</option>
    <option value="A6">A6</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="getPrice()" value="Show price"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It's done with jQuery, it will simplify your work a lot.

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks a lot Mifeet! you have really saved me a lot of time and agony! Thanks so much for the help that you have given me it is really appreciated!! Thanks again